# How to kill a Thread in the queue that is waiting to execute a method in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a common method in the main class that is going to be executes by the main thread and also another thread on some condition. The code structure looks like this

```
class Main {
   public static void main(){
      ...some code
      if(..on some condition)
         methodA()
   }
   public void methodA(){
   synchronized(this){
        ..some code
     }
   }
}

class AnotherThread implements Runnable{
   public AnotherThread(){
       Main obj = new Main();
   }
   @Override
   public void run(){
        if(..on some condition)
            obj.methodA()
   }
}
```

This methodA() is synchronized as mentioned in the code. Let us assume that the condition in both the threads evaluates to true and the methodA() is called on the same time. In this case whichever thread that comes first will execute the methodA() first. But the other thread in the waiting state waiting to execute the method. But I want to kill that thread and limit my execution to just one time (i.e. whichever thread comes first must alone execute the method and not the other).

Is this possible. If so how can it be done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maintain a semaphore and lock it when the first thread runs, each runnable reads the semaphore and sees its locked or not. Have you tried that? Check out ```ReentrantLock```

Comment: By my understanding semapahores are also for maintaining synchronization right ? so the same is happening by using the synchronized block right?

Comment: Synchronized allows only one thread of execution to access the resource at the same time. Semaphore allows up to n (you get to choose n) threads of execution to access the resource at the same time. In your case, i have assumed you are using synchronized to restrict code execution upto only one thread at a time. Infact, owing to satisify your condititon, you can simply lock the execution to the thread and check for other conditions so other threads can execute the same logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your code won't work, because you are using `this` (object level lock) in `synchronized`  block and both the threads are using separate object so both will run without waiting. 
   You can have class level lock  and use that in `synchronized`  block like below:

   ```
   private static final Object LOCK = new Object(); 

   public void methodA(){
       synchronized(LOCK){
        ..some code
      }
   }
   ```

   Or use same object in both the thread.
2. You can't kill the thread, what you can do is have one semaphore (or any variable) and one condition inside  your `synchronized`  block. Check if semaphore is set then return else execute the code and set the semaphore before exiting the method.

   ```
   private static boolean condition = false;// you can you semaphore too class level variable
   public void methodA(){
         synchronized(LOCK){
              if(condition){ return;}// returning if already executed
              ..some code
              // Set condition to true so then again it should not run
              condition = true;
         }
   }
   ```

Comment: By doing this will the condition value be the same for both the threads. I mean to say that, the method should be executed by the first coming thread and should not execute for the thread that is in the queue.

Comment: @Srikanth check the point one, you need to either have static lock object on class level or use same object of Main class in both the thread.

Comment: Let me understand this. You are suggesting to use a LOCK variable that is shared by both the threads, and in anytime if two threads access the same method the first will set the lock to true which in turn will stop any other thread from executing the method. Is my understanding correct or am I going wrong somewhere

Comment: Lock is just lock to prevent both the there running at same time, it's static because you are using different objects in different threads. In above example i suggested to set a static variable  to true

Comment: So you are suggesting me to have a synchronized() on LOCK object followed by a semaphore ?

Comment: @Srikanth I have write down the code above for both, why don't you use it and play around. See if this solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am actually trying to work with threads that calls the function more than once(i.e continually). But I think your solution sets the condition = true after the first time the method gets executed by any thread and cannot be executed by any other threads after that. I actually want to stop the execution of other threads only at that particular time, i.e. I want to make the condition = false after all the threads in the queue return without executing the method. Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

you can't kill the thread in the queue but you can blocked the queue by using poison pill

Answer (score 0):

you can use singleThreadExecutorPool to perform the task, it will allow to execute the thread in sequentially.